# Why OS with deadlock are not that good?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I started learning OS and understanding it's concept but can somebody explain as to why is it bad for an operating system to have a deadlock system?

Comment: IME, deadlock is easily detected - an aspect lf the app functionality locks up with 0 CPU use.  I have also found it easy to fix.  A deadlock-avoidance system that is somehow built in to the OS is an expensive luxury that I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I gathered it's not bad for a system to have a deadlock prevention system, but if an OS has a deadlock prevention system then it may slow down the system as whenever a process or thread will request for a resource then first the system will check if there's any possibility to have a deadlock situation and also such system might be expensive. So, that's why most systems ignore deadlock.